# Tableau - Sorting 3 Levels Hierarchy

Tags: sorting, tableau-api, hierarchy, ranking

I am struggling to keep the value sorted in a descending order when I drill down to my hierarchy levels.
I know there are a few examples in this website, but I couldn't find anything with 3 hierarchy levels... I attached what I am trying to do using the RANK, but as you can see it doesn't seem to be working.
 
What I want to do is to keep the descending order for each level of the hierarchy (category, company, brand).
I am using Tableau 10.3
 
Thanks for your help!
Marta

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jjmH.png)

Comment: If you right-click on those three dimension pills on Rows and look at sort, what is it currently sorting by?

Comment: Yes, they are all correctly sorted by the value I need, but when I click on the hierarchies they do not maintain the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You should uncheck the **Company Name** from your Table Calculation, then the rank won't restart for each one and it should be in descending order within each Category.